# How to move a remote egit repository?

Tags: egit, spring-tool-suite

We're using the Groovy/Grails tool suite from Spring (similar to STS), version 3.1, and have an eGit remote repository on a shared network drive.  That network drive is going away and we need to move it somewhere else.  I have found instructions on how to move local repos, but not remote repos.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?  I've also seen warnings against disconnecting the repository when searching for ways to do this as apparently re-importing became troublesome.  I did try copying the repository to another location, deleting my project, and re-importing but the wizard still contained references to the old location (I think they were just default repository settings set within the tool suite) and I wasn't sure that this would be the best practice.

Being relatively new to git, and quite frankly not a huge fan yet, I'm unsure as to how to proceed.  I see documentation on cloning and adding repos, but not how to move one.  I've also put forth an argument for using gitHub but that won't happen before I need to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: copy the repo anywhere you want and just update the remote in your clone (see the .git/config file or man git-remote)

Comment: Thanks cfrick, that's pretty easy.